# can't run install or have list of gems in ruby or even know their version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I can't use any command on `gem`,after downloading ruby and the gems package,i use the list command `gem list` but i got a problem `undefined local variable or method 'list'`.

Comment: It feels to me like you are trying to use `gem` in Ruby or IRB, but `gem` is a command line tool, not a Ruby method.

Comment: *edited*thanks i didn't know that it is used in CMD not IRB,still a noobie :D

Answer (score 0):

Set "C:\Ruby\bin" Path in Environment Variables then try gem list in cmd.